# Просмотр пользователя из базы

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Осваиваем asp.net. Получили из базы данных MSSQL список пользователей (имён). Сейчас стоит задача каждое имя сделать кликабельным с просмотром подробной информации каждого пользователя из БД. Покажите пожалуйста пример, или соответствующую информацию по этому поводу.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вам [сюда](https://www.asp.net/learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как вариант можно попробовать так
вернуть и контролера в представление инфу про пользователей

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Users = context.Users.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

потом в представлении сделать список

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var user in ViewBag.Users)
        {
            <li><span>Пользователь: @user.Name </span>@Html.ActionLink("Подробнее", "UserInfo", new { Id = user.Id})</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

потом при нажатии идет запрос в метод UserInfo куда передался Id пользователя 
он будет получен из базы и передан в представление которое вернет метод UserInfo

```
public ActionResult UserInfo(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.User = context.Users.FirstorDefault(g => g.Id == Id);
        return View();
    }
```